# MVC Route URL to Area controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, maproute

Hi I want to route to my AdminLoginController (inside Admin area) with this url `siteurl/admin`. My code in `RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)` function:

```
    context.MapRoute(
                    "Admin_1", 
                    "Admin", 
                    new { controller = "AdminLogin", action = "Index" }        
                );
    
//    the default route map

    context.MapRoute(
                    "Admin_default",
                    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller="AdminLogin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

However I can only go to my desired page through `siteurl/Admin/AdminLogin` , not `siteurl/Admin`.

If I change the custom route as:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_1", 
                "", 
                new { controller = "AdminLogin", action = "Index" }        
            );
```

then I can go to my desired page (AdminLogin Index page) when using url `siteurl/`.

How can I customize the MapRoute to go to my page with `siteurl/Admin` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate this in a blank project with just a home and admin login controller, but it appears that the following route should work as expected:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller="AdminLogin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

The issue you are having may well be due to the order, as if placed after the default route, it fails, as when supplied "siteurl/Admin" it will first match the default route.

Comment: Is your `AdminLogin` Controller inside Admin area? The "Admin_default" map route is the default generated. By default, inside Global.asax the Area registration is registered before Route config => so the route in Area will be search first when it read "siteurl/Admin" ? Anyway with that default I cannot reach AdminLogin controller with "siteurl/Admin"

Comment: Oh I don't know why but after clean and rebuild I got the desired route. :)))